# Terraform: auto-scaling ecs service using modules

Tags: terraform

We have a use case where we wanted to scale ECS services. There are about 10 services. I don't want to add scaling code in each of the service modules. Also, I don't want to create a module for this and call them for each service in root module main.tf.

In the below code there are only a few variables which would change for the example service name, target group arn etc.

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "ecs_target" {
  max_capacity       = "${var.max_capacity}"
  min_capacity       = "${var.min_capacity}"
  resource_id        = "service/${var.cluster}/${aws_ecs_service.rc.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "ecs_policy" {
  #count              = "${var.auto_scaling_enabled}"
  name               = "rc-ecs-auto-scale"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = "service/cluster/${aws_ecs_service.rc.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ALBRequestCountPerTarget"

      resource_label = "${var.alb_arn_suffix}/${aws_alb_target_group.rc.arn_suffix}"
    }

    target_value       = "${var.threshold_value_to_scale}"
    scale_in_cooldown  = "${var.scale_in_cooldown}"
    scale_out_cooldown = "${var.scale_out_cooldown}"
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target"]
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it with a module or without modules but with a module is more elegant.

1) Create a module with the above resources with a count of 10 for each resource above so you can loop through them.

2) Call the module with with an array of 10 values for each parameter for each service.

```
module "services" {
  service_names = []
  capacity = []
  ...
}
```